# What software would most commonly be used to create this UI animation from dribbble?

Tags: gui-design, animation, software

I wonder what software is commonly used to create this kind of UI animations.

Click on the links below to see them in action (note that due to stackexchange.com, limitation I cannot show animated gifs here):

- https://dribbble.com/shots/2128443-Liferay-Card-Flow-Isometric
- https://dribbble.com/shots/2278322-Adding-a-new-goal-animation
- https://dribbble.com/shots/2243068-ZARA-Apple-TV-app

Comment: none of you images are animated, not even on the links. Anyways, if it's a gif, just any software capable of making animated gifs

Comment: @Devin, I believe you are using a mobile device right now?
I've noticed that the animated gifs on dribbble will not play on mobile. and of course any software can do it, I'm asking what is the most commonly used

Comment: no, a Macbook Pro, and teh files are jpg so I know for sure they won't animate

Comment: ok, I fixed it.

Comment: well, again, just any software capable of making animated gifs, going from Adobe Photoshop to free open source Gimp to any kind of low cost software you find

Comment: I think...not sure, but OP is referring to the animations that the .gifs are showing. Such as the div in the last link that seems to wobble in 3D.

Comment: @Devin it's not that simple. Photoshop and Gimp are remarkably inadequate or at best terribly inefficient tools to create said UI animations with.

Comment: All three of the linked animations can be created with Adobe After Efects which is great for 2d motion graphics and has some 3d capabilities. If you want to bring flat illustrations to life or orchestrate the sliding in and out of UI components, After Effects is a good choice.


A less common, but growing technique is to generate a prototype, with a tool like Framer, and make a screen recording of yourself interacting with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to lift a quote from an answer [over at DesignerNews](https://www.designernews.co/stories/36434-ask-dn-software-for-ui-animation):

> Framer, After Effects, Cheetah 3D (yes, really!), Hype, Photoshop (for
>   hacky GIFs), Quartz Composer and Form are all worth taking a look at.

On top of that, not from personal experience but from asking around myself, I've found "**After Effects**" to be the answer very, very often.

There are a lot of tools out there that *can* produce said animations, but those are some of the more reliable/efficient ones out there!

***.edit:*** I think this is actually a very fair question, since a lot of standard image-editing tools don't offer the quality/efficiency required to make animations of this level.